# Why Value is auto round-off while using Circumflex('^' symbol) to get square or cube?

Tags: javascript, math, rounding, calculation

I was going to calculate BMI with javascript code in which I've created two variables named height and weight.

You may know the formula of getting the BMI is,
**BMI = Weight(kg) / (Height(m))^2;**

but I got right answer only after writing **Height*Height**.
height*height gives exact answer but height^2 gives answer with rounded-off value.

So I want to know why the operator or symbol "^" is rounding off the value that I want to square.

Comment: Not sure about java script. but `^` is hardly ever exponentiation... Check the operator specification in the language of your choice. Or instead of `(X^2) ` try `(X*X)`.

Comment: Ya It's (x**2). Here ** is used as exponent operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must to use **Math.pow**

"^" this is not squaring

Code for your example:

```js
const weight = 100
const height = 300

const result = weight / Math.pow(height, 2)
// The same as going height^2, height to the power of 2
```

Comment: Yes your right but I want to know about exponent operator, but later on I just research and found that (**) is used as exponent operator. Thanks for your answer.